# Is it possible for a closed manifold to deformation retract onto a proper subset of itself?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a closed (compact, without boundary) topological manifold. Is it possible for there to exist a subset $A$ of $M$ such that $M$ deformation retracts onto $A$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of my answer. I'll assume $M$ to be connected; $n$ stands for its dimension. Suppose $M$ deformation retracts onto a proper subet $A$.

Because $M$ deformation retracts onto $A$, the long exact homology sequence (**LEHS**) of the triple $\emptyset\subset A\subset M$ with coefficients in $G=\Bbb Z$ or $G=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ (depending on wether $M$ is orientable or not) tells us $$H_*(M,A)\equiv 0.$$

Using the above and the LEHS for $A\subset M\setminus\text{pt}\subset M$, there are isomorphisms $$H_{*-1}(M\setminus\text{pt},A)\simeq H_*(M,M\setminus\text{pt})\simeq H_*(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^n\setminus 0).$$ The first one is the connecting homomorphism, the second one arises from excision. Therefore $H_*(M\setminus\text{pt},A)=0$ for $*=n,n+1$
Then, the LEHS of the triplet $\emptyset\subset A\subset M\setminus \text{pt}$ in degree $n$ tell us that

$$H_n(A)\simeq H_n(M\setminus \text{pt})$$

---

Since $M$ is closed connected, its top homology is isomorphic to $G$, and so is that of $A$ since they are homotopy equivalent:
$$H_n(M)\simeq H_n(A)\simeq G.$$ Also, since $M\setminus\text{pt}$ is a non compact connected manifold, its top homology is $0$:
$$H_n(M\setminus\text{pt})=0.$$

This contradicts the isomorphism $H_n(A)\simeq H_n(M\setminus \text{pt})$. Thus there are no deformation retractions of $M$ onto a proper subset.

Comment: A formally essentially identical argument but slightly more direct is to observe that the degree of the identity map is $1$. But if the manifold is homotopy-equivalent to a proper subset, the identiy map would have degree zero.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question: how do we know that the top homology of a non-compact connected manifold is 0?

Comment: @user15464 I don't remember the argument, but I believe it's a theorem in Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes*. If I'm not way out of line, I think it's got to do with the fact that any cycle will have compact support, but I don't recall the argument.

Comment: @RyanBudney Is this because a map that misses a point will have degree zero? I know the argument for maps from $\Bbb S^n$ to itself (stereographic projection), but why does it hold (if indeed it does) for compact manifolds other than the sphere?

Comment: There's a formula for computing the degree as a signed count of points in the pre-image of a regular value.  A point not in the image is a regular value.

Comment: Cher Olivier, could you please write down explicitly the long exact sequence you are using? I am not sure what you mean by the long exact sequence of a triple (rather than the LES of a pair).

Comment: @Bruno given a triple $(X,A,B)$ (that is $X\supset A\supset B$) there are connecting homomorphisms $$\partial=\partial_{X,A,B,n}:H_{n+1}(X,A)\to H_n(A,B)$$ for a long exact homology sequence: $$\cdots\stackrel{\partial}{\to}H_{n+1}(A,B)\to H_{n+1}(X,B)\to H_{n+1}(X,A) \stackrel{\partial}{\to}H_{n}(A,B)\to\cdots$$
where all the other maps are induced by the inclusions of pairs.
This follows from the long exact homology sequence defined by a short exact sequence of complexes, here $$0\to C_*(A,B)\to C_*(X,B)\to C_*(X,A)\to 0$$, where the $C_*(A,B)$ are the relative singular chain complexes.

Answer (score 3):

By a corollary of the generalized Poincaré duality, referred as *Poincaré Alexander Lefschetz duality* in the book *Geometry and Topology* of Bredon, you can derive the following tool :

> **Corollary 8.5 (Bredon - G. & T.)** If $L$ is a proper compact subset of an orientable connected $n$-manifold $M$, then $\check H^n(L; G) = 0$ for any coefficient group $G$.

The same is true with $\mathbb Z/2$ coefficients if $M$ is not orientable. If $M$ retracts on a proper subspace $L$, then $L$ is closed.

But for any proper closed subset $L$ of $M$, by this property from Bredon, we have $\check H^n(L;\mathbb Z/2)=0$. This implies that $L$ can't be a deform retract of $M$, otherwise $L$ would have a non vanishing top homology, as $M$ does.